# Center coordinates of a country in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers

I would like to get center coordinates of a country using Javascript. Is there any xml file that provides this kind of data, for use in a web application? I am basically trying to put data on the map using country names in OpenLayers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) you can use the [Geocoder](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder) class for this.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode(
    { address : "Germany" },
    function(results) {
        window.alert(results[0].geometry.bounds.getCenter());
    });
```

You might want to examine the `results[]` array a bit more than just getting index 0, but this should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I really dont want to use Google API's due to their licensing terms. You have to show the data on a Google map, otherwise you cant use it. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You might have download a suitable GIS dataset and generate the information you want yourself. For example:

- http://koordinates.com/#/layer/1103-world-country-boundaries/

With a program like [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) you can calculate the centroids of each county and generate a table from the country name and x/y.

Note that Koordinates also has a vector API that allows you query features by location and optionally pull out full geometries:

- http://support.koordinates.com/entries/20182948-vector-query

OpenLayers *can* load full geometries and calculate centroids (eg [OpenLayers getCentroid Docs](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Collection-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection.getCentroid)) but considering the size and complexity of a world boundaries dataset, performance won't be very good.

**Putting them together**

Your best option is probably this: once you've got the centroids from the countries, use the Koordinates Vector API (without getting the geometries) to determine which country the selected point is in. From the response, lookup the centroid by name from your data file and centre the map on this location.